# About How to fetch redirecting url html in qt process?

Tags: python, redirect, qtwebkit

When qt process a 301 link ,it will get the redirected html content, but I want to fetch the first link`s html content, example:

When I request the url `http://10.1.1.1/one.php` ,server will return header `location: http://10.1.1.1/two.php` and  some content "redirecting",then it will redirect the url "two.php" and return the two.php's html content, webkit's function "page().mainFrame().toHtml()" can  only fetch the later html content, but i can`t get the previous html content ("redirecting"), I searched the internet several days but nothing helped.

What can I do?